# Checkout from Git and deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, teamcity

I would like to clone a project from a Git server and then perform some tests and then deploy to Heroku.

I have been able to get my project from Git, and then perform "bundle install" which does succeed. Leaving the middle tests part out, I am unable to deploy to Heroku. To deploy, I am doing a Command Line build runner with my "Command Executable" set to "git" and "Command Parameter" set to "push git@heroku-#{new_project}:#{new heroku project’s name}.git master". Where I have set my project name and heroku project name. This is the build log:

```
[21:22:28]: Checking for changes
[21:22:29]: Clean build enabled: removing old files from /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c463bb084d1493f0
[21:22:29]: Clearing temporary directory: /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
[21:22:29]: Checkout directory: /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c463bb084d1493f0
[21:22:29]: Updating sources: server side checkout...
[21:22:29]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Will perform clean checkout
[21:22:29]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Clean checkout reasons
[21:22:29]: [Clean checkout reasons] Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[21:22:29]: [Clean checkout reasons] "Clean all files before build" turned on
[21:22:29]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Building clean patch for VCS root: PROJECTNAME Git Repo
[21:22:29]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Repository sources transferred: 76.91Kb total
[21:22:29]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Removing /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c463bb084d1493f0
[21:22:29]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Updating /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c463bb084d1493f0
[21:22:29]: Parameter "system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir" is undefined.
[21:22:29]: Publishing internal artifacts
[21:22:29]: [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.start.properties.gz file
[21:22:29]: Step 1/2: Bundle Install (Command Line)
[21:22:29]: [Step 1/2] Starting: /home/teamcity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@ PROJECTNAME/bin/bundle install
[21:22:29]: [Step 1/2] in directory: /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c463bb084d1493f0
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rake (0.9.2.2)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using multi_json (1.0.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using activesupport (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using builder (3.0.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using i18n (0.6.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using activemodel (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using erubis (2.7.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rack (1.3.5)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rack-cache (1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rack-test (0.6.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using hike (1.2.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using tilt (1.3.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using sprockets (2.0.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using actionpack (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using mime-types (1.17.2)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using polyglot (0.3.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using treetop (1.4.10)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using mail (2.3.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using actionmailer (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using arel (2.2.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using activerecord (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using activeresource (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using ansi (1.4.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using bundler (1.0.21)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using execjs (1.2.9)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using json (1.6.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rdoc (3.11)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using thor (0.14.6)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using railties (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using coffee-rails (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using jquery-rails (1.0.18)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using libv8 (3.3.10.4)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using pg (0.11.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using rails (3.1.1)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using sass (3.1.10)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using sass-rails (3.1.5)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using sqlite3 (1.3.4)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using therubyracer (0.9.9)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using turn (0.8.3)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Using uglifier (1.1.0)
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2]  [32mYour bundle is complete! It was installed into /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@ PROJECTNAME [0m
[21:22:30]: [Step 1/2] Process exited with code 0
[21:22:30]: Step 2/2: Deploy to Heroku (Command Line)
[21:22:30]: [Step 2/2] Starting: git push git@heroku-PROJECTNAME:HEROKUPROJECTNAME.git master
[21:22:30]: [Step 2/2] in directory: /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c463bb084d1493f0
[21:22:30]: [Step 2/2] fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
[21:22:30]: [Step 2/2] Process exited with code 128
[21:22:30]: [Step 2/2] Step Deploy to Heroku (Command Line) failed
[21:22:30]: Publishing internal artifacts
[21:22:30]: [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[21:22:30]: Build finished
```

It seems like it cannot find my project .git file. I am not sure how exactly to "allow it to find it".
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line from the log:

```
Updating sources: server side checkout...
```

shows that you are using server side checkout whereby the clone happens on the server and the files are copied to the agent.

Change it to agent checkout in your VCS settings and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as soon as I do agent checkout then I get VCS (GIT) error since I am using a password approach which is not supported by agent checkout. Apparently I have to do default private key. Does anyone know how to set that up? I am getting a lot of problems doing that. I got the private key working but not the default private key.

EDIT: I am getting a VCS connection error.